# Default fallback intent invoked after sign in event

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm sending this response from my python webhook to invoke the account linking in my dialogflow chatbot for Google Assistant.

```
return make_response(jsonify({
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": "true",
            "systemIntent": {
                "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
                "data": {}
            }
        }
    }
}))
```

So once the user completes the authentication process, it goes to **default fall back intent**. I want to know that why it's redirecting the user to default fallback intent.

**Can I redirect the user to the Default welcome intent or any other intent?**

P.S. As Account linking is not done on the simulator, I'm not able to see the response it sending once the account linking done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new Intent that is set to handle the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` Event, and then handle this Intent in your fulfillment as you would any other Intent. You'll get this triggered both if they sign in and if the sign in fails, so you'll need to check the arguments passed along with it (or check to see if you have the auth information).

[image]

Comment: Can't imagine where I was without you @Prisoner! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to get previous intent from where we had initiated account sign in ?

Comment: @rajatsaurastri - It isn't clear that you're asking a question related to this one. I suggest you post a new question, giving details about what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what isn't working. If you can illustrate this with diagrams or screen shots of Intents - even better.